# How to do this in a pythonic way?

Tags: python, syntax

Consider this Python snippet:

```
for a in range(10):

    if a == 7:
        pass
    if a == 8:
        pass
    if a == 9:
        pass
    else:
        print "yes"
```

How can it be written shorter?

```
#Like this or...
if a ?????[7,8,9]:
    pass
```

Comment: *pass* does nothing, therefore I would negate the expression: `if a not in (7,8,9): print "yes"`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the `in` operator:

```
if a in (7,8,9):
    pass
```

Comment: a tuple is prefered as a list obejct

Comment: @dzen: Depends who you talk to.  It's stylistic and being consistent is more important than what you choose, in this case.

Comment: Tuples are usually preferred in such situations because they are faster and more efficient.

Answer (score 15):

To test if *a* falls within a range:

```
if 7 <= a <= 9:
  pass
```

To test if *a* is in a given sequence:

```
if a in [3, 5, 42]:
  pass
```

Comment: The first variant is better, at least for this case!

Answer (score 2):

```
for a in range(10):
    if a > 6:
        continue
    print('yes')
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your original code the direct "pythonic" replacement is:

```
if not a in [7, 8, 9]:
     print 'yes'
```

or

```
if a not in [7, 8, 9]:
     print 'yes'
```

The latter reads a little better, so I guess it's a bit more "pythonic".

Answer (score 1):

```
if a in [7,8,9]
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do, the [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) function can also be interesting:

```
def _print(x):
    print 'yes'

map(_print, [a for a in range(10) if a not in (7,8,9)])
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using lambda.

```
>>> f = lambda x: x not in (7, 8, 9) and print('yes')
>>> f(3)
yes
>>> f(7)
False
```

Comment: Use of the short circuit property of `and` seems to be discouraged. See one of Mike Graham's answers on stackoverflow for the reasons.

Comment: Just because you can use a lambda doesn't mean you should.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is tagged as beginner, I'm going to add
some basic if-statement advice:

> ```
> if a == 7:
>     pass
> if a == 8:
>     pass
> if a == 9:
>    ...
> else:
>    ...
> ```

are three independent if statements and the first two have no effect, the else refers only to

> ```
>  if a == 9:
> ```

so if a is 7 or 8, the program prints "yes". For future use of if-else statement like this, make sure to use elif:

```
if a == 7:
    seven()
elif a == 8:
    eight()
elif a == 9:
    nine()
else:
    print "yes"
```

or use just one if-statement if they call for the same action:

```
if a == 7 or a == 8 or a == 9:
    seven_eight_or_nine()
else:
    print "yes"
```